# Firefox default list of tabs removed?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

Up until recently I was able to set a list of tabs that would open when I open a new Firefox window, but the option to do so seems to have gone away in the last couple of weeks. Was the setting renamed to something that I am not seeing or was this functionality actually removed?

Comment: I will just use a bookmark folder for my initial list of tabs. That's actually a better way in general, because I don't actually always want all of those tabs, I just usually do. : o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to:

- Open Settings -> Home
- On the "New Windows and Tabs" category, select `Custom URLs...`
- Click on `Use Current Pages`
- Or you can add them manually. Each page separated by `|`

[image]